# Change feed observer on multi-region write

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am using multi-region write (and read) cosmos db. I have multiple change feed observers on the same collection, each updating a different search index (each with own lease prefix). Default consistency level is set to Session.

Using SDK v2 (and change feed processor library v2):

```
new ChangeFeedProcessorBuilder()
                    .WithHostName(hostName)
                    .WithProcessorOptions(hostOptions)
                    .WithFeedCollection(collectionInfo)
                    .WithLeaseCollection(leaseInfo)
                    .WithObserverFactory(observerFactory)
                    .BuildAsync();
```

My logs show a situation where 2 out of 3 of those observers received an older version of the updated document:

1. time t1: document1 created
2. time t2 (days after t1): document1 updated
3. time t3:

   - observer1 received document1 (version at t2)
   - observer2 received document1 (version at t1)
   - observer3 received document1 (version at t1)

**Question**: Does the changefeed processor instance have an affinity to a particular region? In other words, is it possible that it reads the LSN from one region and pulls the documents from another? I was not able to find clear documentation on change feed observers and multi-region. Is the assumption that once the processor instance acquires the lease, it will observe changes from the same region consistently, an incorrect assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The region contacted is the default region (in the case of Multi master, the Hub region, the first one in the Portal list), unless you specify a PreferredLocation in `collectionInfo` you are using in `WithFeedCollection`.

`DocumentCollectionInfo` has a `ConnectionPolicy` property you can use to define your preference through the `PreferredLocations` (just like you can do with the normal SDK client). Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.changefeedprocessor.documentcollectioninfo?view=azure-dotnet

All changes are pulled from that region, the LSN returned and the documents are from that region (they come in the same Change Feed response).

Once an observer acquires a lease, it will read changes for the partition that lease is for, from the region defined in the configuration (default is Hub or whatever you define in PreferredLocations).

EDIT: Are you doing a ReadDocument in your observer after getting the changes? If so, with Session consistency you will need the SessionToken from the `IChangeFeedObserverContext.FeedResponse` (reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.changefeedprocessor.feedprocessing.ichangefeedobservercontext.feedresponse?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_ChangeFeedProcessor_FeedProcessing_IChangeFeedObserverContext_FeedResponse)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This was actually a false negative. Observers in another region were still on an older version of our code which produced traces that made us think they were seeing an older version.